# TfsConfigurationServerFactory not found

Tags: powershell

```
$uri = "https://myserver.com:443/tfs"
$tfsConfigurationServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer($uri)
```

gives this error on the power shell script

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory].
```

Adding this line add the dll to only the curreent session.

```
Add-Type -Path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll”
```

My question is what do I need to do/install to get Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory in my pc?
I can see the dlls in this location of my PC.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TestAgent\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
```

I have VS 2017 installed and using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search would've found your answer. Have you not browsed this thread?

[Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366947/unable-to-find-type-microsoft-teamfoundation-client-tfsteamprojectcollectionfac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Tried that and getting this error: Exception calling "GetConfigurationServer" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of 
its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." on this line.                           $tfsConfigurationServer =Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer($uri)

Comment: Did you fetch nuget.exe?